# Share Session State Across Multiple Domains in .net ( NOT SUB Domains )

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, cookies

I am using ASP.net 3.5 w/ C# using SQL Server with Session State stored in the SQL Server DB.

I have an issue with losing session state across multiple domains, but using the same browser instance and same code base.

For example, We are directing customers to **www.MyStore.com** to browse our store and we want to send customers to **www.MyStore.ShopPlatform.com** to checkout w/ secure SSL validation.  The session is being re-created when re-directed to **www.MyStore.ShopPlatform.com**.

The wildcard SSL is installed at www.ShopPlatform.com.

So, The question is.... How do you associate 1 session state cookie to multiple domains (**www.MyStore.com**  and **www.MyStore.ShopPlatform.com**) on the same server using .net?

Answer (score 2):

If you use cookies for session, you don't. The browser won't send cookies to domains that don't match, and you can't set a cookie for all domains. Even if you could, the session cookie is just a key to server-side session and that key doesn't mean anything without access to the session store. A third party won't have that.

If www.mystore.com and www.mystore.shopplatform.com happen to both be backed by machines you own, and both machines have access to the same session store, then you might be able to use a Cookieless ASP.NET Session config to make it work.

Generally speaking, you can't use session this way.

Comment: Thanks... MNGwin... I would think this was be a very common request.

Comment: Perhaps, but how would it even work? Session is all server-side.

Comment: We own dedicated servers and the backend Database, so we have access to everything.

Comment: Then, like I said, you may able to make it work with cookieless ASP.NET session. if the machine key is configured appropriately. It's not that common of a request - generally systems tightly coupled enough that it makes sense to try and share session aren't on separate domains.

Answer (score 1):

Since both domains are different, new sessions will always get created.

I suggest using a shared database approach.

Have a column created in users table that can store a random hash. A datatype of     `uniqueidentifier` should do.

When redirecting user, generate a new GUID and store it for the current user and then append the same to the url being redirected. At the receiving domain, setup an endpoint page that will accept an URL encoded path and query string as `ReturnUrl` parameter and a `tokenId` parameter for the guid.

Here is a dummy code that will redirect the user to a public endpoint along with a dummy query string parameter. The code was hosted on domain1.local

```
Using ctx As New DataContexts.SBWebs
    Dim u As DataEntities.User = (From usr In ctx.Users Where usr.User.Equals(Page.User.Identity.Name) Select usr).FirstOrDefault
    If u Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim id As Guid = Guid.NewGuid

    u.Token = id
    ctx.SubmitChanges()

    Dim newPath As String = "/protected/?tick=" & Now.Ticks
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("http://www.domain2.local/EndPoint.aspx?tokenid={0}&ReturnUrl={1}", id.ToString, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(newPath)))
End Using
```

And the `EndPoint.aspx` contains the following code..

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString.HasKeys AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("tokenid")) Then
        Using ctx As New DataContexts.SBWebs
            Dim usr As DataEntities.User = (From u In ctx.Users Where u.Token.Equals(Request.QueryString("tokenid"))).FirstOrDefault
            If usr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

            usr.Token = Nothing
            ctx.SubmitChanges()

            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(usr.User, False)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

On Security Note: Once the cookie is created, remove the GUID from the table to protect against REPLAY attacks.

EDIT:
Just a word of caution. Don't send user to a ASP.Net protected page (where Deny="?" or something like that is given). Redirect the user to a public end-point that can handle the tokenid and after the setting the cookie, redirect to the intended page.

Comment: Thanks....  Seem like a good deal of development work to get this to actually work..